# Tetris clear lines issue

Tags: c#, tetris

I am making a tetris clone for a project. I'm pretty much done but my clear lines class has a bug that I cant shake. I have made a 10*20 grid which I draw the sprites into. When I get a line at the floor it works fine but above that it just deletes the line and moves everything under it down too. This is the code for my clear line class:

```
public static void ClearLines()
{
    for (int CountY = Game1.LandedBlocks.GetLength(1) - 1; CountY >= 0; CountY--)
    {
        bool clearLine = true;
        for (int CountX = 0; CountX < Game1.LandedBlocks.GetLength(0); CountX++)
        {
            clearLine &= Game1.LandedBlocks[CountX, CountY] != -1;
        }
        if (clearLine)
        {
            for (int CountX = 0; CountX < Game1.LandedBlocks.GetLength(0); CountX++)
            {
                Game1.LandedBlocks[CountX, CountY] = -1;
            }
            for (int y = Game1.LandedBlocks.GetLength(1) - 1; y > 0; y--)
            {
                for (int CountX = 0; CountX < Game1.LandedBlocks.GetLength(0);                   CountX++)
                {
                    Game1.LandedBlocks[CountX, y] = Game1.LandedBlocks[CountX, y - 1];
                }
            }
            CountY++;
            Game1.rows++;
            Game1.score += 100;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could shed some light on what to do I'd really appreciate it. I've tried so much and nothing works :(

Comment: sorry about the formatting on that class. was formatted when i looked at the post

Comment: I've just sorted it out, just need to wait for approval

Comment: I've just edited it, so hopefully it'll be okay shortly.

Comment: please tag with what language you're using. (and there's really a [tetris] tag? *boggles*)

Comment: @Wooble: You can type in any tag you like.

Comment: @user1250838: by `class` I assume you mean `method`.

Comment: @Boo you can only use the predefined tags until you reach a certain reputation then you can tag with anything you like. Tetris is one of the predefined tags.

Comment: yes i mean method. sorry this method is in a class on its own right now

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is with

```
            for (int y = Game1.LandedBlocks.GetLength(1) - 1; y > 0; y--)
            {
                for (int CountX = 0; CountX < Game1.LandedBlocks.GetLength(0); CountX++)
                {
                    Game1.LandedBlocks[CountX, y] = Game1.LandedBlocks[CountX, y - 1];
                }
            }
```

This (I think) moves all the lines down one line. The problem is with the loop boundaries always going to line 0. You should only be moving the lines above whichever line you are clearing. Change the `y > 0` to `y > lineNumber` where `lineNumber` is the line you cleared.

Comment: thanks a mill for the advice. got me to where i needed to be. the problem was with the (y = Game1.LandedBlocks.GetLength(1)) in the first for loop. Was not reading the line to be cleared but your advice is absolutely what helped me find it